# Faster approach to replace part of XML file: XMLDocument or TextStream?

Tags: xml, vb6, filestream

I have an app in VB6 to store sales information into database. While user is entering data I want to store it into a local XML file so as to avoid losing data because of network failure, etc. So when each item row is entered, the row is appended into the XML file.

I was thinking of appending the new row data into the file so it wouldn't have to read any existing data. But as XML requires closing tag, this doesn't seem to work.

So I think I would have to read the file, remove last tags and append the rest of the data with the closing tag. Would this be the right method? What would be the best approach performance-wise? Using XMLDocument or TextStream?

Comment: This sounds way too complicated. Considered something that manages the data (not to mention ACID) aspect already? For instance, a local SQLite database ..

Comment: i would be storing only one entry at a time which may contain may be upto 100 rows of items. once saved this to the database it be removed. Would it be a bad idea ?  Please suggest. i actually did not want to install any local DB for this

Comment: Well, if someone suggested something to me, the *first* thing that I would (or should) do is to [*go look it up*](http://www.sqlite.org/). Then I would be able to see for myself if their suggestion was valid (or not) for my scenario.

Comment: ok sorry for the miscommunication actually my question was why do you think the xml storage is too complicated? is it reading the file or the frequet writes to it which gets hit? (btw i am reading sqllite now)

Comment: Because to do it correctly is complex, as noted. The XML can be kept in a DOM and them written on each DOM change - which is an *easy* approach, but the DOM is always resident in memory and each write must rewrite the entire file. Or, have to write/read/write/read approach or, if structuring it as a log/journal, it'd be write/write/write/read. I'm a lazy programmer - I don't like to do extra work (unless it's fun).

Comment: Another approach might be to not create a valid XML file, but rather create a file of a journal/list of XML *fragments* (with a restriction that records can only be *added* to the end to it). That is, don't create a root element, but have each record added be it's own top level element. Then there is no issue with having to deal with a closing tag (outside of required closing tags for each fragment).

Comment: yup got it. thanks i would try that... yeah there are some limitations as it is vb6.

Answer (score 1):

As this is done in one "session", just keep the `XMLDocument` object in memory, appending new nodes to it and saving the file each time a row is added.
If you need to recover the session, just load the XML into that same object, and carry on as before.

This saves a full load, parse, save each time, or attempted string parsing.

Comment: but i need to preserve it outside the session. evenif the software gets closed also i need the data to be recoverable. I was also looking at the option of using sqlite DB as suggested in the above comment. That seems an option. but facing some issue in driver installtion. thankyou very much though

Comment: @user1616785: Then just load the XML file back into that same object when you restart the session. You can then append nodes to the end of this and save as you were doing before.